# how to get the key and value of a dictionary inside an arraylist in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i want to loop through a arraylist which contains dictionary inside.

```
foreach(Dictionary<string, string> tempDic in rootNode) 
{ 
    Response.Write(tempDic.key + "," tempDic.value + "<br>"); 
}
```

how to access the dictionary key and value?

Comment: What do you mean by "the dictionary key and value?" Dictionaries have multiple keys and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you also need to loop inside the dictionary and in order to do that you can iterate the `tempDic` using `Foreach`.

```
foreach(Dictionary<string, string> tempDic in rootNode) 
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> _x in tempDic)
    {
        Response.Write(_x.key + "," + _x.value + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: but the arraylist only has 12 row, has which row only has one dictionary, but use 2 foreach will print out about 62 row of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ first to get a list (actually `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`) of all `KeyValuePair`s:

```
var pairs = rootNode.OfType<Dictionary<string, string>>()
                    .SelectMany(d => d.AsEnumerable());
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> tempPair in pairs)
{
    Response.Write(tempPair.Key + "," + tempPair.Value + "<br>");
}
```

So, it'll be enough to do only one foreach loop. The other one would be done for you by LINQ.